# A complicated question about views, pls help~

Tags: views

May I ask how to achieve this requirement? There is a task content type, which has an applicant field, which is multi-valued (that is, a task allows multiple people to apply at the same time), which refers to the paragraph type applicant, and the paragraph type applicant has an applicant (referring to the user entity) field and an application status field, both of which are single values. It is expected that when the applicant requests a task, the task will disappear from the applicant's (currently logged in user) task list view, how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

The way it SHOULD work is to create a view to list Work items. Then add a contextual filter for the Applicants field. In that filter under "When the filter is not available" set to "Provide default" and select "User ID from logged in user".

As this is, this will give you ALL the Work items which the user is added to, but you want the opposite of this. Now scroll to the bottom of the filter settings and under More, select Exclude.

This should give you what you want, but on my test D9.5 site it does not work. I would suggest this is a core bug.

Comment: Thanks. It works for me!

Comment: Interesting. Wonder why it doesnt for me. Glad it helped. Can you pick my answer as the answer then?

Comment: Sorry, I only tested the following cases before. At first, the worklist of user1 and user2 contained work1 and work2. Then user1 applied for work1, user2 applied for work2, and the worklist of user1 contained work2. user2's worklist is left with work1, which is correct.
But just now I continue to test, let user1 also apply for work2, work2 is still in user1's worklist, and work1 and work2 both appear in user2's worklist.